Can we verifiably query an older part of the state with smoldot light client?
I am trying to understand what can be done with a light client, particularly how it can query historical blocks.
If for example, i added some data to a system.remark at block number 1,000,000, could i then query the block with a Smoldot light client at a later time when that block is no longer "pinned"?
if no, what is the limitation? (mind you, the system.remark is not the important element here, we can use preimage or anything else)
if yes, how is that query result verified? i.e. can the full node provide a result that we can verify?
